# Assembly references of PackageReference missing when building with jenkins and devenv.com

Tags: c#, jenkins, nuget, packagereference

I'm building a solution that contains a class library, a UnitTest Project and a .vdproj setup project. Because MSBuild cannot handle vdproj I'm using devenv.com. I'm calling `C:\NuGet\nuget.exe restore "%WORKSPACE%\solution.sln" -ConfigFile C:\NuGet\NuGet.config` before the build starts and build with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" rotring.tacton.export.sln /build "ci"`.

After that I execute the tests with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "%WORKSPACE%\testproject.test\bin\ci\tests.dll"`.

The nuget restore command tells me that every package has been restored correctly and to the right place:
`Added package 'package.1.9.11' to folder 'C:\dev\workspace\solution\packages'`.

But still I'm getting the error:
`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'sometype' does not exist in the namespace 'somenamespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Local builds just work fine even when I'm executing the console build mentioned above manually.
Do I need to restore the packages somehow with devenv.com? Isn't the advantage of PackageReference that all packages are stored at the same place compared to packages.config?

**Update:** I managed to find a partly myself. One thing was that my Test-Project was not migrated to PackageReference and caused an error.
However I was able to build the solution by first restoring the packages with MSBuild:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Restore /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\NuGet\NuGet.config"`

And then building the solution with devenv.com:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" solution.sln /build "ci"`

Now the only problem I face is that msbuild only restores the packages from the main project and doesn't care about the Test-Project.

Comment: Have you tried using `nuget.exe restore` command without specifying any arguments?